Exporting pointset.UnstructuredGrid data as STL file from pyvista
I am using pyvista to mesh 3D scan data of terrain and save them to stl files to save in blender. Some of the .xyz files contain data for a single continuous area while others include a number of smaller areas, with no data inbetwean.
I have managed to get this to work for the continuous regions:
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv

xyz_path = r"Path_to_file.xyz"
stl_path = r"Path_to_file.stlr"

data = np.loadtxt(xyz_path)
cloud = pv.PolyData(data)
surf = cloud.delaunay_2d()
surf.plot(show_edges=True)
surf.save(stl_name)

for the discontinuous reqions I got large faces linking the different areas that I would like to delete. I found a way to do this based on the area of the face.
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv


xyz_path = r"Path_to_file.xyz"
stl_path = r"Path_to_file.stlr"

data = np.loadtxt(xyz_path)
cloud = pv.PolyData(data)
surf = cloud.delaunay_2d()

cell_sizes = surf.compute_cell_sizes(length=False, area=True, volume=False)
areas = cell_sizes['Area']
max_area_threshold = 100  # Set the area threshold

# Create a mask for cells that meet the area criteria
valid_cells = areas < max_area_threshold

# Use the mask to filter out large triangles
filtered_mesh = surf.extract_cells(valid_cells)
filtered_mesh.plot(show_edges=True, scalars='Area')

surf.save(stl_name)


From the plot I can see that the correct elements have been deleted. However, this process also converts the data structure from core.pointset.PolyData (which can be saved to stl) to core.pointset.UnstructuredGrid (which cant be saved to stl).
Is there a way I con convert the core.pointset.UnstructuredGrid object to a format that can be saved to stl or delete the unwanted elements in a way that I can still save the surface to stl.
My current workaround is to create the STL file leaving in the unwanted faces then delete these in MeshLab but if possible I would like to avoid this step if there is a simple solution.

Depends on your mesh. There's extract_surface() that gives the surface mesh of your unstructured grid, but of course this loses information if your grid has anything other than faces. Without a runnable example I find it hard to visualise what's exactly going on in your code, so you'll have to make sure that you don't end up with junk (i.e. unexpected changes compared to your original faces).

Thanks @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні. Ill try extract_surface() later (I have managed to corrupt my environment with  pyvista installed so need to fix that first before I can fix this)

Thanks @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні. I managed to test extract_surface() and it worked. I can now save the surface to stl once I have deleted the elements larger than my cutoff.

Glad to hear. You should either answer your own question here, or delete it. It's up to you :)

Based on the input from Andras I used extract_surface() to extract the surface and save to stl file.
import numpy as np import pyvista as pv
    
    
xyz_path = r"Path_to_file.xyz" stl_path = r"Path_to_file.stlr"

data = np.loadtxt(xyz_path) cloud = pv.PolyData(data) surf = cloud.delaunay_2d()

cell_sizes = surf.compute_cell_sizes(length=False, area=True, volume=False) areas = cell_sizes['Area'] max_area_threshold = 100  # Set the area threshold

#Create a mask for cells that meet the area criteria 
valid_cells = areas < max_area_threshold

#Use the mask to filter out large triangles 
filtered_mesh = surf.extract_cells(valid_cells) filtered_mesh.plot(show_edges=True, scalars='Area')

#Extract surface
filtered_mesh_surface = filtered_mesh.extract_surface()
filtered_mesh_surface.save(stl_path_filtered)

This is covered in the documentation here: https://docs.pyvista.org/version/stable/examples/01-filter/extract-surface.html.
